# codeigniter 4 - Loading helpers and user_agent library in model

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I've been struggle with this for hours. I would like to use helpers and the user_agent library on a model.

1. User_agent: every-time I'm trying to load the user agent library using the next code:

   $agent = $this->request->getUserAgent();

I getting the next error:

> ```
> Error
> Call to a member function getUserAgent() on null
> ```

2. When trying to load helper and use it from model for example cookie helper:

helper(cookie);

I think it's loading the helper but when trying to use it I printing next error:

> Error Call to a member function is_mobile() on null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There isn't any need to load helpers.*

[User Agent Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html#user-agent-class)

> The User Agent Class provides functions that help identify information
> about the browser, mobile device, or robot visiting your site.

```php
$agent = \Config\Services::request()->getUserAgent();
$isMobile = $agent->isMobile();
```